# XAMPP phpMyAdmin failed with #2002

Tags: windows, xampp, user, phpmyadmin

New test server running Windows 7 64 bit.  I installed XAMPP and created a seperate user other than the root.

When I created another account and initiated XAMPP I was able to get localhost but when I go to phpMyAdmin I get

> Error
>   MySQL said: 2002 Connection for control user as defined in your configuration failed.

I attempted to create a user under admin but it still does not work.  How can I allow users to be able to use phpMyAdmin but not under admin rights?

**EDIT:** I did create a test user as ABCadmin with admin rights and still am not allowed phpmyadmin access.

[image]

Comment: Your question is absolutely on topic here. On Stack Overflow, not so much. [webmasters.se] *might* be an option, but it can stay here, no worries.

Comment: thanks I was lost in where it should go.  Ive searched for days on a solution to the issue but I dont know if its within Windows 7 or XAMPP