# Access virtual desktop LAMP on Windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, xampp

I was having issues getting XAMPP to run for users other than admin per this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/563820/xampp-phpmyadmin-failed-with-2002?noredirect=1#comment689307_563820).  Trying to figure out a solution I had an idea and was curious to know how to make it work.  I installed [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with [Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  I was able to install and run LAMP successfully.  Now in virtual, localhost works and references that particular test environment.  If I access localhost on the Windows side I can get XAMPP to work in localhost (admin only).  How would I be able to get access to the virtual environment from the Windows side per browser or IP?

Answer (score 0):

In network settings of Virtual Machine use NAT. Restart it. Then on your windows browser try accessing ubuntu's ip.

Comment: would that IP still be accessible across the LAN?

Comment: no. only via the same host.

Comment: Use bridge network to share the VM in LAN. You will have to configure a static IP. So it doesn't change.

Comment: that doesnt work and disables all internet access in virtual.